# How do You Unit Test a Custom Assert?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, assert, junit4

I'm writing my own JUnit Assert? How do I test it?

I know how to feed it something that will pass and something that will make it fail, but how do I write a JUnit test for those things?

The custom assert will look something like:

```
public static void assertSomething() {
    if (!something()) {
        fail("Expected something, but ...");
    }
}
```

How can I catch that fail?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`fail()` throws a `junit.framework.AssertionFailedError`, which you could catch in a unit test of your assertion method, if you like.

Example:

```
@Test(expected = AssertionFailedError.class)
public void testMyAssertFails() {
    assertSomething("valueThatWillFail");
}

@Test
public void testMyAssertPasses() {
    assertSomething("valueThatPasses");
    //if you reach this line, no failure was thrown
}
```

Comment: Given that different testing frameworks provide their own AssertionFailedError, a more stable approach is to catch `java.lang.AssertionError` instead of framework-specific `junit.framework.AssertionFailedError` or `org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError`.